# Corda doesn't synchronize the attachment's fileName

Tags: corda

I have a question regarding **uploading attachment** in Corda. 
In my application, I would like to attach a pdf in the transaction from provider to receiver. I used the method called `uploadAttachmentWithMetadata` method with a fileName to it to generate the hash.

Here are some simplified code snippets I tried:
Firstly, I get the hash

```
val pdfHash = proxy.uploadAttachmentWithMetadata(
                    ByteArrayInputStream(pdf),
                    identity,
                    "fileName")
```

Then I added the hash to the transaction:

```
txBuilder.addAttachment(pdfHash)
```

Once the transaction is done, I can retrieve the pdf by using the fileName in the provider side. However, I can not do the same thing in the receiver side. I checked the database in the receiver side and I couldn't found the fileName for each attachment, while provider does have it. So my question is: does Corda `synchronize` the fileName between nodes for the attachment? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here I answer the question myself. 
After some discussion in the `Corda` slack channel and online searching, it seems that the MQ only "share" the attachment to the counter-party without its file name.
So, to fetch the attachment:

for provider party, you can get by name or get by hash:

```
val ids = proxy.queryAttachments(
    AttachmentQueryCriteria.AttachmentsQueryCriteria(filenameCondition = Builder.equal(fileName)),
    null
  )

...

proxy.openAttachment(it)
```

for receiver party, if you really want to get the attachment, store the hash (in the state, or somewhere), then get it by hash.

```
proxy.openAttachment(SecureHash.parse(hash))
```

This is how I solve it in my special case. If you guys have any better idea, please leave your comments. I will really appreciate it.